# Is my XML code correct for adding a css and javascript file?

Tags: magento-1.9, xml

I want to add a css file and a javascript file to one of my magento pages:

```
<reference name="head">
<action method="addCss">
<stylesheet>css/styles2.css</stylesheet>
</action>
</reference>
<action method="addJs">
    <script>js/flickity.pkgd.js</script>
</action>
```

this is my code. The css file is loading but the js file isn't. Is there something wrong with it and when yes, could you help me with editing the code so it should work properly? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

move js code into head reference

```
 <reference name="head">
<action method="addCss">
<stylesheet>css/styles2.css</stylesheet>
</action>
</reference>
<action method="addJs">
    <script>js/flickity.pkgd.js</script>
</action>
```

change to this

```
<reference name="head">
<action method="addCss">
<stylesheet>css/styles2.css</stylesheet>
</action>
<action method="addJs">
    <script>js/flickity.pkgd.js</script>
</action>
</reference>
```